# get substring and convert to integer in javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
const [top, bottom, left, right] = [txtStyle.getPropertyValue('top'),
          txtStyle.getPropertyValue('bottom'),
          txtStyle.getPropertyValue('left'),
          txtStyle.getPropertyValue('right')];
```

Values are assigned as "24px" etc. But I want to assign it as 24 (int). Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: `parseInt("24px")` === `24`. Is that the solution you wanted?

Comment: `assign it as 24`, seems `parseInt("24px")` would work

Comment: parseFloat() did the work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
const [top, bottom, left, right] = [parseInt(txtStyle.getPropertyValue('top')),
  parseInt(txtStyle.getPropertyValue('bottom')),
  parseInt(txtStyle.getPropertyValue('left')),
  parseInt(txtStyle.getPropertyValue('right'))
];
```